# Is there possible to use elastic cloud search in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I found that in react elastic search work proper as well I found code of expo also. But not for react-native.
Reactive search I found package but this was 3 years old not update anything on that project. And also giving me lot of issue. So please tell me that any other way to use elastic search with react-native.
If not then please let me know any alternative way to do that functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the ElasticSearch web API?

Comment: can you please send me link or something for reference because I not find any solution yet. @Abe

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rest-apis.html

Comment: There is any library for react-native ? How can I use @Abe

Comment: Why do you need a library? A library would just be a wrapper over these network calls anyway. Use axios/fetch requests to the web.

Comment: Ohh okk thanks for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that answer

we don't use from our side to make elastic data in use,

for elastic data possible from the backend side.

simply backend developer can provide you elastic API

and use from front end side as we simply call API

Hope this can help you